# Resources for proof-writing in highschool geometry

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, book-recommendation, online-resources

I'm a middle school student, and I'm beginning geometry this year. I'd like to practice/learn how to write proofs on my own, besides doing in-class work, and I was wondering what some good resources were for this. The resources would need to be beginner-level, as I've only "written" (aka, copied down from the whiteboard) one proof before.

I do have a general idea of what a proof should be like: a t-chart with the math on the left and the theorems/rules you are using on the right, with the given at the top and the result on the bottom. If there is also a list of commonly used theorems/rules I could use, that would be helpful as well.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You say that you would like to practice and learn how to write proofs of your own. Well, practicing and learning are actions and therefore, take time. I think you should know the story about Albert Einstein. When he was in school, he did not do very well in mathematics. Later, when he was beginning to think about his ideas which eventually developed into his theory of relativity, he had to teach himself about the work in geometry that had been done by Bernhard Riemann.

Here are some online resources: 
http://handsonmathinhighschool.blogspot.com/2012/07/made4math-geometry-proofs.html

http://www.mathguide.com/lessons/GeometryProofs.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hogZsmU5_lQ

Comment: Thank you for responding. I'm not quite sure the point of the first paragraph; I know that learning takes time. As for the resources, thank you the second seems helpful. It might be good if you describe them for future viewers.

Comment: Einstein not doing well in high school is a myth http://www.abc.net.au/science/articles/2004/06/23/1115185.htm